# How to get always correct type without explicit conversions

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Here is my problem. I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class C1
{
    public C1 GetThis()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class C2:C1
{

}
```

Now, I want to use those classes the following way:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    C1 c1 = new C1().GetThis(); //1st line
    C2 c2 = new C2().GetThis(); //2nd line
}
```

However, the second line does not work. To make it work I have to cast like this:

```
C2 c2 = (C2)new C2().GetThis(); //2nd line
```

But, I am a very lazy guy and try to avoid writing explicit conversions (casts).
So the question is: how should I change the implementation/declaration of the GetThis() method so that the 2nd line works without any casting?

Thank you for any tip.

Answer (score 4):

> how should I change the implementation/declaration of the GetThis() method?

One possibility would be to declare the method in the class `C2` with the corresponding return value using the `new` modifier:

```
public class C2 : C1
{
    public new C2 GetThis()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

the [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)

> explicitly hides a member that is inherited from a base class

Answer (score 3):

The exact thing you're asking for is not possible in C#. There is no return type that says "the return value is `this` thus its type is known". There is no point in it from a type system perspective, since returning `void` already gives the caller all the required information (the caller already has the object it made the call on). From a C# perspective, it's true that it can lead to cleaner code.

One way around it is with generics:

```
public class C1<T> where T : C1<T> {
  public T GetThis() { return (T) this; }
}

public class C2 : C1<C2> { }
```

This is not as type-safe as a true "returns `this`" type or annotation, since it allows `C3` to derive from `C1<C2>` as well, which would cause an exception to be thrown at run-time, there would not be a compile-time diagnostic for this.